# Finding the mass in the tank of an air compressor from gage pressure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, compressors

I am solving the following problem:

> The tank of an air compressor has a volume of 3 cubic feet and is
>   filled with air at a temperature of 40 °F. If a gauge on the tank
>   reads 150 psig, what is the mass of the air in the tank?

The given answer is 1.78 lbs.

This is just $PV = mRT$, so I try:

$$    T = 40+460 = 500\ \mathrm{°R}$$

$$    P = (150\ \mathrm{psi_g} + 14.7\ \mathrm{psi_{atm}})*144 = 23,716.8\ \mathrm{\frac{lbf}{ft^2}}$$

$$    R = 53.34\ \mathrm{\frac{ft*lbf}{lbm*°R}}$$

$$\frac{PV}{RT} = m =  \frac{23,716.8\ \mathrm{\frac{lbf}{ft^2}}*3\ \mathrm{ft^3}}{53.34\ \mathrm{\frac{ft*lbf}{lbm*°R}}*500\ \mathrm{°R}} = 2.67\ \mathrm{lbm}$$

Is the problem set wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible the problem set is wrong? or am I missing something?

Probably, your calculations are correct I calculated $m$ to be $2.6697$ $lbm$ myself.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to divide by 1.5 at the bottom of your equation.
Try it and see, but I suggest you use exact values to start good habits.